# Script to change file permission

Tags: unix, file-permissions

I am trying to create a file permission shell script to change all the folders to `chmod 664` and all the files to be `chmod 775`

```
find -type d
```

Can I use the above command and how can I do this recursively for all the folders starting from the specific directory and only do the change in that directory.

Comment: Please follow the below answer and accept the one. So that it helps for others

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
$ find / -type f -print -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

and

```
$ find / -type d -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: I want to restrict to a specific folder? can I give the folder name after \

Comment: This start changing everything in my user and endup even going to entire root, really bad suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To run it on current directory and sub-directory files we need to use '.' in the find command as follows,

```
find . -type f -print -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -type d -print -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

A slight change in earlier answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to restrict the files or folder use `-prune -o`  :-

```
find . -iname youname_of_files_or_folder -prune -o -type f -print -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```